# How to run all the scenarios of one feature file in single browser instance with selenium,serenity & cucumber

Tags: selenium, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am not able to execute selenium,cucumber & serenity scenarios of one feature file in single browser instance and currently each scenario is running in new browser instance

Below are my configurations:

**Serenity and Cucumber version:**

serenity.version=1.2.2-rc.1

serenity.cucumber.version=1.1.16

**serenity.properties details:**

serenity.use.unique.browser=true

restart.browser.each.scenario=false

Please let me know what other configuration i need to do to run all scenarios in one browser instance

Answer (score -1):

```
serenity.use.unique.browser=true
serenity.restart.browser.for.each=STORY
```

(there can be also `NEVER` - for not closing browser even between Stories)

I've managed to add above and the SCENARIOS in one STORY would run without closing browser.

Check also if you have any Step that includes CLOSING the browser.
Take into account also what you have in `@AfterStories` and `@AfterScenarios`.